# Loop over each failed rule with jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I need to be able to loop over the current failed rules after my form has been validated using the jquery.validate library.

I've looked at the following:

```
$('form').validate().errorList
```

This returns the message and element of the error, but not the rule/name of the rule that failed.

```
$('form').validate().errorMap
```

This just returns an element ID/message pair.

```
$('form').validate().settings.rules
```

This returns a list of all elements and their associated rules, but no value that indicates which ones are currently failed.

I need something that contains both the element (or its ID) and the rule that failed.  Of course, an element may be mapped to more than one failed rule.

If there's an event I can hook into with the unobtrusive library (as not all events seem to be supported unobtrusively) that will give me the rule and element on failure, this would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking a method you can use with an extension, you can do something like this:

```
//update FormatAndAdd function to store failed rule values in data
var oldFormatAndAdd = validator.formatAndAdd;

validator.formatAndAdd = function (element, rule) {
    oldFormatAndAdd.apply(this, arguments);
    $.data(element, "failedMethod", rule.method);
};

var oldCheck = validator.check;

//update check to remove failed rules from data if element is valid
validator.check = function (element) {
    var result = oldCheck.apply(this, arguments);
    if (result) {
        $.data(element, "failedMethod", null);
    }
};
```

I just store the rule info in data but I'm sure you can update this to manipulate errorList instead.

Answer (score 0):

The validate() function initializes the widget; it does not validate the form. You need to specify a handler for an invalid form, like so:

```
$("form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
```

Once you've done that, the **validator** object will contain an array of invalid elements in it's **errorList** attribute.

Full documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Going with your comment, you could theoretically modify line 585 to include the rule method into the errorList:

```
this.errorList.push({
    method: rule.method,
    message: message,
    element: element
});
```

I've tested it with basic rules, but if you have custom function validators you should try those too.

Comment: I understand that.  In my examples above, I am referring to the validator object returned from `$('form').validate()`.  As I stated above, the `errorList` array on the validator object returns only the element and the message, but not the rule -- I need the rule with the element.

Comment: @JeradRose Updated response. Had to modify the source a little.

Comment: Thanks @MikeRobinson.  Unfortunately, I can't really modify the source.  Well, I technically could, but this is an enterprise solution, and they don't want the issues that would arise when updating the library and forgetting we have custom code in the jquery library.  I either need a way to extend the library from another file, or find a built-in way.

Comment: Acutally, ironically, the reason I need this is because I already have a different solution in place for doing what I need, which was accomplished by updating the jquery library. And after discussions, it was determined we need another way without modifying jquery source.

Comment: rule.method was added to jquery-validate back in 2014, see [pull request 1035](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/pull/1035) so you can find the rule name (e.g. "required") in errorList[0].method within your showErrors function.